# How to redirect to .php file if exists and another if it doesn't

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, forum

I've only just written a forum in PHP. In my database, under my posts table and my categories table, I have a field called 'slug' for the url.

I have urls like /html for my HTML category and /html/test for a post named test under the HTML category.

But I also want urls like /signin which redirect to signin.php.

Is there a rewrite condition I can use that if I go to, for example /something, it will chech if something.php exists. If it does, it will show the content of something.php, else it will show category.php?cat_id=something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a rewrite condition I can use that if I go to, for example /something, it will chech if something.php exists. If it does, it will show the content of something.php, else it will show category.php?cat_id=something?

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# exclude legit requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# check if requests is pointing to a php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]

# otherwise, serve the category (also need to exclude legit requests)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category.php?cat_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple php [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function

```
if(file_exists("require.php")){
    require_once("require.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$ /$1.php [QSA,L,E]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /default.php [L]
```

Comment: I also need to be able to go to /html which does not exists, and have it redirected to /view_topic.php?topic_id=html

Comment: change default.php by view_topic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)-function in php in combination with the [header](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)-function. 
This should result in something like:

```
if(file_exists("file.php")){
     header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get your value then use

```
if (file_exist("[yourvalue].php") {
   header("Location: [yourvalue].php");
}
else {
   header("Location: categories.php");
}
```

Comment: But as "laurent" said, i would do url rewriting to change ?categories=html&post=test into /html/test so you still can you $_POST[] to get your values

Comment: It is possible to tell your access .htaccess that if it encounters a specific file to redirect it to another specific file. You could google for htaccess redirect and read about that.